# how react js acts as a websocket client?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I want to create a Websocket based client-server Application. In that I'm created node js websocket server which is waiting for the clients. Now I want to create react js websocket client. I'm using react js as a websocket because I have to render elements continuously which server sends as a simple text message.

I'm struck at implementing the react js as  a websocket client. How it should work as a websocket client and how it will send request to the websocket server just like this :

```
'ws://localhost:1234'
```

I want to know more about websocket client and also want to solve this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest you read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications, before asking any other questions.

Comment: ok ... read this page...But I want to implement that in the react js...my question is that only how I can implement websocket client in react js?

Answer (score 31):

So a very basic example without much overhead would require two things:

1. a component with a reference to websocket connection
2. an event listener on the connection that updates the state of the component
   when a message arrives

<strike>Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47360/</strike>
Demo (2019): http://jsfiddle.net/643atLce/

```
class Echo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { messages : [] }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    // this is an "echo" websocket service
    this.connection = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');
    // listen to onmessage event
    this.connection.onmessage = evt => { 
      // add the new message to state
        this.setState({
        messages : this.state.messages.concat([ evt.data ])
      })
    };

    // for testing purposes: sending to the echo service which will send it back back
    setInterval( _ =>{
        this.connection.send( Math.random() )
    }, 2000 )
  }

  render() {
    // slice(-5) gives us the five most recent messages
    return <ul>{ this.state.messages.slice(-5).map( (msg, idx) => <li key={'msg-' + idx }>{ msg }</li> )}</ul>;
  }
};
```

Comment: - Hey, It sounds good...but I'm facing **Bad JSFiddle configuration, please fork the original React JSFiddle** error, I think my structure is not valid, Please tell me how to make structure for my react app? i.e. html,js,webpack.config.js & package.json

Comment: Where do you get this error? On the demo fiddle linked in my answer?

Comment: yes...I'm just placing js code n change ws url and In html we are using using this <script>, so that this error is getting...

Comment: For anyone having trouble with the jsfiddle link above. After clicking the link you can see a HTML Select that has a value of "Javascript". Flip this select to "React" then click the Run button in the upper left of the page. That's how I got the example to work for me.

Comment: @Frito updated the link in my answer. The fiddle was made long ago by forking the "React Base Fiddle" (I think there was no predefined React config in jsfiddle back then). Thanks!

Comment: I encounter this error message ```InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable``` when i open ur fiddle. why??

Answer (score 1):

Just create rest program from server side and create the connection at a Web page.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost/echo', ['soap', 'xmpp']);

opening the connection 
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // 
};


connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};

//to receive the message from server
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};

// Sending String  
connection.send('your message');
```

At server side you will get session and message,  So you can do communication with N sessions.

Comment: This answer will sufficient only for plain javascript. the question is about to put this answer into reactjs. So you are not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your react Project folder in App.js add a websocket connection & listen for the messages coming from the websocket server.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
   super();
    this.state={
      endpoint:"ws://localhost:1234",
      messages:[]
     }
   }

  componentDidMount(){
  //initialize connection
   const ws = new WebSocket(this.state.endpoint)
    ws.onopen = () =>{
     //send any msg from Client if needed
       ws.send(JSON.stringify(temp))
  }
   //save whatever response from client
    ws.onmessage = evt =>{
     this.setState({
      message:this.state.message.concat(evt.data)
    })
  }
 }
 render(){
 return(
 <div>
 <p>{this.state.message.map(items=><li>{items}</li>)}</p>
 </div>
)}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I leave here a Functional Example (all of the above are Objects...)

```
const client = new WebSocket(ws://stream.marketpricesfun.com)
const [cottonPrice, setCottonPrice] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    client.onopen = () => {
        client.send('{"topic": "subscribe", "to": "newPrices"}')
    }

    client.onmessage = (message) => {
        if (message.data) {
            const parsedData = JSON.parse(message.data)

            setCottonPrice(parsedData.cotton.price)
        }
    }

    return () => {
        client.close()
    }
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of us use hooks, to handle the `Websocket` connection, but here is mine, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75592270/10646511) is simple and you will not get mess up in the future cases once your application getting bigger