# How to implement automatic reloading of components upon receiving updates via web sockets in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, redux

I currently have a React JS web app which displays data in a table by calling an API. Now I have a requirement of opening a web socket, listening to it for any updates and then reloading/updating the table component to show the newly added values. How to implement such a solution using React and Redux? I have tried libraries but dont know how to develop a complete implementation. If there is any tutorial or guide, please refer to them.
Below is my current implementation.

```
    class TableExp extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
  super();

  this.state = {
      tableData: [{
          resourceID: '',
          resourceType: '',
          tenantName: '',
          dealerID: '',
          status: '',
          logFilePath: '',
          supportPerson: '',
          lastUpdatedTime: '',
      }],
  };
 }

      componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('API_URL', {
    headers: { 

    },
    responseType: 'json',
  }).then(response => {
      this.setState({ tableData: response.data });
  });
 }

 render () {
  const { tableData } = this.state;

  return (<ReactTable
    data={tableData}
    noDataText="Loading.."
    columns={[
              {
                Header: 'Details',
                columns: [
                          {
                            Header: 'Support Engineer',
                            id: 'supportEngineer',
                            accessor: d => d.supportPerson,
                          },
                          {
                            Header: 'Tenant Name',
                            accessor: 'tenantName',
                          },
                          ],
              },
              {
                Header: 'Info',
                columns: [
                          {
                            Header: 'Dealer ID',
                            accessor: 'dealerID',
                          },
                          {
                            Header: 'Status',
                            accessor: 'status',
                          },
                          ],
              },
              {
                Header: 'Logs',
                columns: [
                          {
                            Header: 'File Path',
                            accessor: 'logFilePath',
                          },
                          ],
              },
            ]}
    defaultPageSize={20}
      style={{
        height: "450px" // This will force the table body to overflow and scroll, since there is not enough room
      }}
    className="-striped -highlight"
  />
    );
}
};

  export default TableExp;
```

EDIT: The answer pointed out in the comments , I have gone through that, however it really does not solve the problem Im facing. If someone can give me guidelines or solution based on the code I have posted above that would be really helpful.

Comment: Please see the below link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122068/how-react-js-acts-as-a-websocket-client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how react js acts as a websocket client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122068/how-react-js-acts-as-a-websocket-client)