# Proper way of using React hooks + WebSockets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I need to connect to WebSockets server and log it's messages. With React class component I'd put this logic in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and move on happily, but I'm not sure how to properly implement it with hooks.

Here's my first attempt.

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

export default function AppWs() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com/');
    ws.onopen = () => console.log('ws opened');
    ws.onclose = () => console.log('ws closed');

    ws.onmessage = e => {
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log('e', message);
    };

    return () => {
      ws.close();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>hooks + ws</div>
  )
}
```

I added connection and log logic to `useEffect`, provided empty array with dependencies, and everything worked great. Until I needed to add `pause` state to pause logging.

```js
export default function AppWs() {
  const [isPaused, setPause] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com/');
    ws.onopen = () => console.log('ws opened');
    ws.onclose = () => console.log('ws closed');

    ws.onmessage = e => {
      if (isPaused) return;
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log('e', message);
    };

    return () => {
      ws.close();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPause(!isPaused)}>{isPaused ? 'Resume' : 'Pause'}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

ESLint started to yell at me that I should add `isPaused` state as a dependency to `useEffect`.
Well, ok, done.
But I noticed re-connection to WS server after every time I click the button. This is clearly not what I want.

My next iteration was to use two `useEffect`s: one for connection and one for message processing.

```js
export default function AppWs() {
  const [isPaused, setPause] = useState(false);
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const wsClient = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com/');
    wsClient.onopen = () => {
      console.log('ws opened');
      setWs(wsClient);
    };
    wsClient.onclose = () => console.log('ws closed');

    return () => {
      wsClient.close();
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ws) return;

    ws.onmessage = e => {
      if (isPaused) return;
      const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
      console.log('e', message);
    };
  }, [isPaused, ws]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setPause(!isPaused)}>{isPaused ? 'Resume' : 'Pause'}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This works as expected, but I have a feeling that I miss something and this task can be solved easier, with one `useEffect`.
Please help to refactor the code on convince me that I'm using React hooks in a proper way. Thanks!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As you are only setting the web socket once, I think a better approach is to use a ref instead of a state:

The order of `useEffect` is important.

As suggested by George in the comments, in the first `useEffect` `ws.current` is saved to a variable to make sure that when `close` is called it refers to the same instance.

```
export default function AppWs() {
    const [isPaused, setPause] = useState(false);
    const ws = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        ws.current = new WebSocket("wss://ws.kraken.com/");
        ws.current.onopen = () => console.log("ws opened");
        ws.current.onclose = () => console.log("ws closed");

        const wsCurrent = ws.current;

        return () => {
            wsCurrent.close();
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!ws.current) return;

        ws.current.onmessage = e => {
            if (isPaused) return;
            const message = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log("e", message);
        };
    }, [isPaused]);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setPause(!isPaused)}>
                {isPaused ? "Resume" : "Pause"}
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: when I use this code I notice that the websocket closes and then reopens after each received message. Any ideas why it's doing that?

Comment: By the way, you should store the newly created websocket to a separate variable and us it for the cleanup. Not the `ws.current`. Some other code can mutate the `ws.current` and the old websocket instance will not be closed by cleanup. The connection will remain open and cause bugs

Comment: @Alvaro - hoping if you could please look at thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69476080/client-to-retrieve-data-from-backend-server-database-table-via-a-websocket-conne

Comment: @Alvaro, I used your exact code to solve my websockets issues too. Thanks :) But why useRef? I read the docs and it is supposed to be used to reference a DOM element. But here this is not the case. Could someone explain how it is being used here?

Comment: I found a good answer to my own question here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/  Refs aren't just for DOM elements apparently. The key points are, they persist between component refreshes, and don't trigger a component refresh when the value is changed. Ideal for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws.kraken.com');
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  const a = JSON.parse(event.data);
  setPriceWebSocket(a);

  const amin = socket.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      event: 'subscribe',
      pair: ['XBT/USD', 'XBT/EUR', 'ADA/USD'],
      subscription: { name: 'ticker' },
    }),
  );
  

});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We all know that react are reactive in terms of state and re-rendering, we don't want to mess up the current connection while our application keep listening on some events, most of the answers I saw was to put it on the `useEffect` wherein they handle the ws connection using `useRef`, here is the caveat, everytime the component state change, it rerender the components at the same time your websocket connection also mess up

```
useEffect(()=> {
  ws.current = new Websocket('URL')
  ws.current.on('some-event', () => {
    // console.log(state) will not get update unless we add it as dependency
  })
}, [...])
```

there will be a time that connection will cast frequently and react might suddenly re-render at the same time, and there is a chance that the client connection will also cast as well depends on how many times your react re-render, and yes backend as well might get in trouble, as a React Developer, we hate unnecessary re-render just because of one state change.

**NOTE:** handle properly the re-renders and states of your React Application, if you wont get mess up in the future.

So, How do we address that?, remember that our application has an entry file `index.js`, we can put above your socket configuration and where the state management libs are, so here how I properly end this up

```
//socket.ts
const client = new SocketClient(WEBSOCKET_SERVER_URL, {
  namespace: 'chat',
  messageType: 'bytes'
});
client.connect(() => console.log('SUCCESS CONNECTION'));
client.error(() => console.log('ERROR CONNECTION'));

const socketConfig = (store: Store) => {
  // ... do something here
  socket.on('some-event', () => {...});
};
export {socket}
export default socketConfig


//index.ts
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

import store from 'ducks'; //lets assume this is our state manager
import socketConfig from 'api/socket'

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root') as Element;
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

socketConfig(store);

root.render(<App store={store}  />);

//status.js
import {socket} from 'api/socket';
...
  useEffect(() => {
    const statusListener = () => {...}
    socket.on('status-event', statusListener)
    return () => {
        socket.remove('status-event', statusListener);
  }, [])
...
```

the `SocketClient` is a factory class that based on `Websocket`, you can create your own of course