# Why react JS hooks websocket onmessage reset state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I am struggling with using Web socket in ReactJS.

I have followed this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161181/12962511

This solution works pretty good!

However, I wonder why onmessage is in useEffect.

I tried onmessage in the useEffect with [] which is componentDidMount. This results reset my states but not starting the function from the beginning because useEffect with [] did not get triggered in this case.

So my question is:

1. The difference between put onmessage in useEffect with [] or in just useEffect.
2. The necessity of useRef in react Hooks websocket (I tried both ways and it looks pretty same on network console.) - I know useRef prevents making websocket every re-render.

I have stuck this issue for all day long. :(
Please help me.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. `useEffect` without dependencies will be triggered every render. As you need to make subscription only once, it should be with empty decencies `[]`.
2. In your example, `useRef` is used only to pause listening to messages via websocket. If you don't need this logic, you able to not use it.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have done putting onMessage with empty dependency [] and it causes my message state empty. On the other hand, when I put onmessage in useEffect this situation was not occurred. I really want to know the reason happening this situation. Thank you so much! Ramil!