# React state is always null with Socketio

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-state

Im using Socket.io for my React app and Im facing a weird issue.

Here is the code of my component :

```
function ImageToGuess(props){
    let socket = useContext(socketContext)
    let [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState(null)
    let [pixelImage, setPixelImage] = useState(null)

    let onImage = async (data) => {
        setBaseImage(data)
    }

    let onPixelize = async pixelSize => {
        console.log(baseImage) // <--- baseImage is always null but why ??
        let jimg = await jimp.read(baseImage)
        jimg.pixelate(pixelSize)
        let pixelImage = await jimg.getBase64Async(jimp.AUTO)
        setPixelImage(pixelImage)
    }

    //Sub/unsub events
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('image', onImage)
        socket.on('pixelize', onPixelize)

        return () => {
            socket.off('image', onImage)
            socket.off('pixelize', onPixelize)
        }
    }, [])

    //Tell the server we stored the data in the state
    useEffect(() => {
        if(baseImage){
            socket.emit('imageReady', props.roomID)
        }
    }, [baseImage])

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

The server is sending me data, I store this data in a state called "baseImage", I emit the "imageReady" event when the state is not null then the server start emitting me "pixelize" events but I don't know why I have an error saying me that "baseImage" is null even if I checked it before sending the "imageReady" event.

When I check the state with React devtools I see data in it !

Thx for any help.

EDIT

The solution is to reasign the handler when the state change, I don't think/know if it's efficient but it works.

New code :

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('image', onImage)

    return () => {
        socket.off('image', onImage)
        socket.off('pixelize', onPixelize)
    }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if(baseImage){
        socket.off('pixelize', onPixelize)
        socket.on('pixelize', onPixelize)
        socket.emit('imageReady', props.roomID)
    }
}, [baseImage])
```

Comment: It captured the first value of `baseImage` when `useEffect` was called once, then the updated function, even if redefined each render, is never used.

Comment: Another way would be to [add dependencies to the `useEffect` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60152922/1218980), though I'm not sure it's efficient to sub/unsub each update.