# React - state variable not reflecting changes

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am working on adding websockets to my Node/React app to automatically reflect changes to all the clients.  So I have a websockets helper module that has onclose, onopen and onmessage events as well as a readyState function.  So my component that needs the updated websocket values makes a call to that module and gets back data.  That data variable is coming over empty, but when I console it out in the onmessage event in the module itself, it has all the info I want.

So here is how I call the websocket module in my component:

```js
const onConnected = (socket) => {
    socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
            eventType: 'clientCount'
        })
    );
};
    const { socket, readyState, reconnecting, data } = useWebsocket({
        url: wsURL + ':' + process.env.REACT_APP_WS_PORT,
        onConnected
    });
```

I have a useEffect that should spit out the updated values from data:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('data changed!!!!');
    console.log({ data });
    console.log({ socket });
    console.log({ readyState });
    if (data) {
        setNumberClients(data.numberClients);
        setNumberIpads(data.numberIpads);
    }
}, [data, readyState]);
```

And finally here is my websockets module itself:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function useWebsocket({ url, onConnected }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [reconnecting, setReconnecting] = useState(false);
    const socket = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('running socket hook');
        socket.current = new WebSocket(url);

        socket.current.onopen = () => {
            console.log('connected');
            onConnected(socket.current);
        };

        socket.current.onclose = () => {
            console.log('closed');
            if (socket.current) {
                if (reconnecting) return;
                setReconnecting(true);
                setTimeout(() => setReconnecting(false), 2000);
                socket.current.close();
                socket.current = undefined;
            }
        };

        socket.current.onmessage = (e) => {
            const wsData = JSON.parse(e.data);
            console.log('message received ', wsData);
            //setData((prev) => [...prev, wsData]);
            setData(wsData);
        };

        return () => {
            socket.current.close();
            socket.current = null;
        };
    }, [reconnecting, url]);

    const readyState = () => {
        if (socket.current) {
            switch (socket.current.readyState) {
                case 0:
                    return 'CONNECTING';
                case 1:
                    return 'OPEN';
                case 2:
                    return 'CLOSING';
                case 3:
                    return 'CLOSED';
                default:
                    return;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };

    return {
        socket: socket.current,
        readyState: readyState(),
        reconnecting,
        data
    };
}
```

So data is always an empty array when I console it out in my component.  But in the websockets module, it(wsData) has the info I need.

**One More Thing:** I am following the tutorial here: https://github.com/devmentorlive/websocket-direct-chat-client/tree/2-as-a-hook/src/chat

**Update 2:**  I have a github repo showing the exact issue here: https://github.com/dmikester1/websockets-test
Use Server and Start scripts to kick things off.

Comment: Can you please add: `if(data && data.length) console.log({data})` just before the last `return` in `useWebsocket()`, and also add the same line just above your `useEffect()` that does `console.log('data changed!!!!');`, and share the result? I can't see any mistake right now but that extra logging might provide some extra insight.

Comment: That never prints anything out.  If I set a default value for data, it does.

Comment: Ok, and is `console.log('message received ', wsData);` logging what kind/type of data? can you share some examples? Also: which "default value" did you set for data that made it work?

Comment: Mind sharing a minimal reproducible example, like a GH repo or codepen?  I'm also curious on why it's not working and want to help.

Comment: @dmikester1 your `onclose` handler coupled with `reconnecting` being in the useEffect watchlist may be causing some shenanigans. Try deleting both. If this works, I could write a more detailed answer to fix the onclose problem.

Comment: @deckele I assume you are talking about those changes in the websocket module.  I removed `reconnecting` from the watchlist and commented out the `socket.current.onclose = () => {` handler.  No change to the functionality.

Comment: @tmilar `wsData` is an object with properties like number of clients, number of ipads, device details, etc.  I will see if i can duplicate it on CodePen.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I'm not sure there is a way to duplicate it on Codepen because of the use of Websockets and the backend server.

Comment: Although this may help, I am following the tutorial here: https://github.com/devmentorlive/websocket-direct-chat-client/tree/2-as-a-hook/src/chat

Comment: can you share a minimal repo that can reproduce this instead? I'll clone and test it

Comment: @tmilar I finally created a new repo and cleaned out all the irrelevant private stuff.  I have duplicated the issue in this cleaned up repo.  I have it uploaded here: https://github.com/dmikester1/websockets-test

Comment: the two scripts to kick things off are `server` and then `start`

Comment: Did you fix it already? I do see `data` coming in on the SchedulePage.

Comment: This is not fixed.  I cannot see the client count up in the top right next to the circled number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem on front-end side.

I think you have used `useWebsocket` hook twice - once in the `SchedulePage` and again in the `ClientCountContainer` so that you can check if `2 clients` are displayed.

The problem is that the `socket` client you defined in `ClientCountContainer` component is not receiving the message from the server.

After looking at the websocket server, I noticed that it broadcasts messages to websocket clients that are saved in `clients` array. Not all the websocket client is saved in this array, but only the client which sends `{eventType: 'connect'}` message to the server is saved in that array.

The websocket client you created using `useWebsocket` hook in `SchedulePage` component is saved in `clients` array on websocket server, because it first sends `{eventType: 'connect'}` message to the server. But the websocket client you created in `ClientCountContainer` is not saved in that array.

Therefore, the messages containing `clientCount` information is not sent to the second websocket client which is defined in `ClientCountContainer`.

To get rid of this from happening, you can simply add this code snippet in the `ClientCountContainer.js`, which sends `{eventType: 'connect}` message to the server so that this client can be added to broadcast array.

```js
    .....
    const onConnected = (socket) => {
        // Add these lines
        socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                eventType: 'connect'
            })
        );

        // This is the original line
        socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                eventType: 'clientCount'
            })
        );
    };
    ......
```

Please let me know if you have further issues.
Thanks.

Comment: OK, I played around with this a ton tonight.  I figured out in the `setupWebSocket.js` file on the Node server in the handler `ctx.on('message', (message)` for type `connect`, when I do `ctx.user = clientID;` it was not persisting for some reason.  But when I do it directly under `wss.on('connection', (ctx, req) => {`, then it persists in the `ctx` object and I can later check for it.  Any ideas why I couldn't do that inside the on message handler?

Comment: That's because `clientID` is generated using `uuidv4()` within that message handler. Each time a new message `{event: 'connect'}` is arrived, it's re-generated, so it can't be persist.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much!  I was able to get it working with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the useEffect would have to run all the time, not only when ur `url` changed or when it is reconnecting.

Try giving this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161181/10691892

Comment: I can't figure out how to adapt that to my code.