# How to access state inside a listener inside a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I understand that without dependencies you cannot access state inside `useEffect`. An example as such :

```
 const [state, setState] = React.useState('')
 const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:5000`)

 React.useEffect(() => {
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log(state)
},[])
```

In this case `state` comes back as empty even though it has changed in other parts of the code. To solve this in principle I should add `state` as dependency to the useEffect hook. However, this will trigger the listener again and I do not want to have 2 active listeners on my `websocket` or being forced to close and reopen it again as such :

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log(state)
},[state])
```

What is good practice when it comes to accessing `state` inside a listener that sits inside `useEffect` hook?

Comment: It can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161181/9294837

Comment: @VitaliyRayets That is not my question.

Comment: you need to store your current state in a `useRef` to make it available to an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

IF you need to re-render the component when the state changes try this:

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('');
  const stateRef = React.useRef(state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, [state])

  const ws = React.useMemo(() => {
    const newWS = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:5000`);
    newWS.onopen = () => {
      console.log(stateRef.current);
    }
    return newWS;
  }, []);
```

This way you create the `ws` only once, and it will use the state reference which will be up to date because of the `useEffect`.

If you don't need to re-render the component when the state updates you can remove `const [state, setState] = React.useState('');` and the `useEffect` and just update the `stateRef` like this when you need.

Like this:

```
  const stateRef = React.useRef(null);

  const ws = React.useMemo(() => {
    const newWS = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:5000`);
    newWS.onopen = () => {
      console.log(stateRef.current);
    }
    return newWS;
  }, []);

  // Update the state ref when you need:
  stateRef.current = newState;
```

Answer (score -1):

Best Practice get data in listeners.[UPDATED]!

```
const [socketData , setSocketData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  websocet.open( (data) => {
       setSocketData(data);
    })
},[])
//second useEffect to check socketData
  useEffect(() => {
   if(socketData){
     // access to data which come from websock et
   }
},[socketData])
```

Comment: My question is accessing state in a listener not useEffect running twice.

Comment: I got you, that you can not get value in listeners especially in websocket so you can define another state and change value when listener executes and then put the value inside a useEffect dependency and add your calculation in useEffect.

Comment: let me update my answer

Comment: check this approach.