# react native websocket connection keeps at readyState 0 (android emulator and device)

Tags: android, react-native, websocket

I have a websocket server which is fine, I can connect from my browser to the webserver.

I want to connect to this socket server from react native, I've implemented the following code:

```
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(new WebSocket('wss://url'));

  const test = () => {
    console.log(ws.readyState);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    test();
  }, [ws]);
```

The readystate keeps at 0, for the emulator and the device I'm using. I tried to connect to echo.websocket.org, but it also keeps staying at 0 (connecting).

When trying to call `ws.onopen()` I get the error `null is not a function`, probably because it's not connected yet. I even don't get an error (when calling `ws.onerror` I get the same `null is not a function` error).

What could possibly be wrong? My socket server is reachable through wss (secure). Even secure doesn't work.

Comment: Check this answer you will find your solution. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161181/13632102)